# PHP - return value from recursive function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have function like this:

```
function show_comments(&$comments, $parent_id = 0) {
      $comments_list = "<ul>\n";
      foreach($comments as $comment) :
        if ($comment["parent_id"] != $parent_id)
          continue;
        $comments_list .= "<li>\n<h2>{$comment['id_comment']}</h2>\n";
        $comments_list .= "<p>$comment[body]</p>\n";


        $this->show_comments($comments, $comment['id_comment']);
        $comments_list .= "</li>\n";
      endforeach;
      $comments_list .= "</ul>\n";

      return $comments_list;
    }
```

At the moment this function is returning only one result (the first one). How can I bind all result and return them?

Comment: It should return all comments. Are you sure in `$comments` you have more than 1 comment and those comments' parent_id are different that `$parent_id` passed as parameter (or 0 if none given)?

Comment: There are 5 comments at the moment. First comment is the parent (with parent_id = 0), and next comment is the child of the previous one (comment 2 is child of comment 1, comment 3 is child of comment 2 and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 10, you call show_comments() but you don't concatenate result.

```
$comments_list .= $this->show_comments($comments, $comment['id_comment']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, you saved me from headache. It works like a charm :) (I was trying to solve this for more than an hour :D ).